# display objects and level

Tags: actionscript-3

how does the display object level work? is it like in HTML where the latest appended or nested element is the highest?

and how can you give a display object a higher level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform an `addChild()` call to a `DisplayObjectContainer`, the appeneded object is placed at the top of the display list relative to the container.

Try to look at the `setChildIndex()` method (and other like `swapChildren()` to change the z ordering of your children.

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29)

Hope this helps.
Ciao

Comment: can you only change the levels for children in a specific container, and not make them "float" outside and higher than the object that contains them? if you understand me? :)

Comment: When you add a child to a DisplayObjectContainer, you can move the child where you want according to the x and y position. Your child always looks "over" the container because it's inside of it. IE. you can have a square at coordinates (100,100) then add a circle inside and move it where you want (-10,-10). The circle will look "over" the square. Obviously all peroperties (x, y and so) are relative to it's container then if you move the container, the child will move itself too. I understood right?

Comment: ok.. I think I get it.. you can't move child "outside" (higher or lower) than the containing object compared to other display cointainers?

Comment: Take a look here :) http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3displaylist/

Answer (score 0):

you can access a display list index using methods from the abstract [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html) class, such as:

```
-  addChild()
-  addChildAt()
-  getChildByName()
-  swapChildren()
```

all DisplayObjects can be children, but not all DisplayObjects can have children (IE: Shape).

DisplayObjects must inherit from DisplayObjectContainer (IE: Sprite) in order to have children.